# Is there a label in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

i'm coming from Java background, Is there a label in HTML, where I could using for example javascript update the value.
I mean by label here, something similar like text input, but not not possible to update it, and it looks non-updateable.

Comment: [CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/css/info) allows one to style elements, like `span` or even `label` (which *is* an HTML element) to look just about however is desired. You can also make an `input` readonly/disabled via the corresponding attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious to create a label would be using `<label>`

```
<label for="coward">Förnamn</label> <!-- points to to input element with id coward -->
<input class="text-input" name="coward" type="text" id="coward" value="whatever" />
```

But I think you're looking for something to "store a value in a form" that shouldn't be editable. You could use a hidden text input for that.

```
<input type="hidden" name="hiddenField" value="whatever" />
```

You could use divs (and style it the way you want it), and then just fetch the html from that div.

Take a look at the other answers as well.

There's a lot of options. What do you actually want to do? It would be easier to give you an answer that suits your needs.

Answer (score 3):

You said you wanted something similar to a text input, so... use one, then!  Just disable it, like

```
<input type='text' disabled>
                   ^It's MAGIC!
```

You don't want `label` literally in HTML, because it's in no way similar to a text input.  Labels in HTML are used for things like putting text in front of radio buttons.

If you wanted something similar to a [Java label,](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Label.html) you would just use the `p` tag, unless it would be behind a text input or so, then you *would* use the `label` tag.

Answer (score 1):

A label is a `<label>`...

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options.

There is actually a `<label>` element, which is typically used for labeling the items in a form.

You could also do a text input (`<input>`) and set it to disabled:

```
<input disabled>
```

Or you could just use a simple paragraph element `<p>` and style it how you want.

Here is a JSFiddle with some examples: http://jsfiddle.net/QXP75/

However, you'd want to use something semantic, so knowing what the purpose is would allow a more specific message. Also, with CSS, you can make just about any element look like anything.